# Publish error while publish the azure pipeline

Tags: git, dataset, azure-data-factory, publish, linked-service

[image: Getting this error while publish the pipeline]I created a azure data factory pipeline in collaboration branch, pipeline is succeeded and I'm trying to publish the pipeline getting one error. Invalid references or dependencies found. This is likely due to publishing outside of Git mode or editing and deleting linked services in other branches.

And publish errors: The document creation or update failed because of invalid references 'xyz'. Please ensure 'xyz' exists in data factory mode and recreate it in Git mode if already present.

Comment: What's your question here? It sounds like you know the root cause and answer. Find who and why did not add referenced object (xyz) and add it or remove reference to it.

Comment: I added screenshot for your reference, I'm unable to publish the pipeline

Comment: Can you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59323766/how-to-fix-the-data-factory-v2-adf-publish-branch-being-out-of-sync-with-the-mas) once?